# iphone - setting a property on another class

Tags: iphone

I have a property declared on a class:

**.h**

```
@interface myClass : UIView {
  BOOL doStuff;
}

@property BOOL doStuff;
```

**.m**

```
@synthesize doStuff;
```

this class is a delegate of another one. On the other class, I am trying to set this property, doing something like

```
[delegate setDoStuff:YES];
```

I receive an error telling me that "method -setDoStuff: not found..."

How do I declare the property on the class, so other classes can read and set them?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your delegate declared as type "id" ?
either you declare its true type MyClass *delegate in the other class (which points to your myclass) or

declare a protocol that delegate has to implement id  in declaration.

Last (but not right approach) is to typecast it [(MyClass*)delegate doStuff].

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you’re importing your custom class’s header and that `delegate` is declared as an instance of that class.

Comment: do I have to import the header? If the delegate is set and is working (and it is, because I can call methods on the delegate), why is the header importing necessary? I mean, If I can access methods on the delegate and the setters/getters are "a kind" of method, why they are not seen by the other class? I don't get it... and btw, I have imported the header and the error persists...

Answer (score 1):

you could also specify the name of **setter** function in `@property`.

```
@property (nonatomic,setter = setMyDoStuff,assign) BOOL doStuff;
```